# Displaying mySQL data in separate tables by date (Using PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Working on a small little project for a group of friends.

Essentially, sport stats are saved into a database and then pulled out and displayed in a table.

Currently it looks like this:

```
Name1 Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 6/15/2015
Name1 Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 6/12/2015
Name1 Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 6/12/2015
Name1 Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 6/12/2015
Name1 Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 6/12/2015
Name1 Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 6/9/2015
Name1 Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 6/7/2015
```

So, all the information is pulled and displays in a single table organized by the date. Instead of displaying every single row in one table, I would like to display a separate table for each date.

So we would have 4 separate tables instead of just the one large one.

```
Name1 Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 6/15/2015

Name1 Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 6/12/2015
Name1 Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 6/12/2015
Name1 Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 6/12/2015
Name1 Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 6/12/2015

Name1 Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 6/9/2015

Name1 Stat1 Stat2 Stat3 6/7/2015
```

I've been struggling with how to do this for a few weeks now, I dont have much time to put into this and my PHP knowledge is limited. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: In your case, it need to create a new table for every day. so it grow your database size. So tell me what is the need to store values in separate tables ?

Comment: From my reading it isn't a separate database table for each date, it is a separate PHP generated HTML display table for each date, pulled from a single database table with a date column.

Comment: dstudeba is correct, my apologies if I made it confusing.

Comment: yeah, you are right @dstudeba

Comment: select column_names from table where date(date_column)='2015-06-15' is this you expect?

Comment: use group_by in date column

Answer (score 0):

Each time that mysql finds a new date insert `</table>` a `<br>` and then a new `<table>` statement

I recomend you to use `css styles`.